# Feeding multiple values into a barcode leaves a '0' barcode. How do I remove this barcode entirely?

Tags: barcode, zpl, barcode-printing, zpl-ii

I have a system currently set up that creates a barcode for a UPC on a label.  This works for single items, but sometimes I have more than one item that tries to feed into that barcode, and when that happens it is set to have no value.

However, instead of there being no barcode, there is actually a small barcode that scans in as 0.  How do I ensure that no barcode appears?

```
 ^FT350,698^BY2,,75
 ^BCN,75,N,N,N^FD$ItemBarCode$^FS
```

"$ItemBarCode$" is an item from a populated table that I do not control, and there can be as many items as needed.  The customer requires no barcode when there are multiple items and requires a barcode when there is one.  Their sample does not use a typical UPC style barcode.

Comment: Sounds like a bad select statement or program logic. And it has very little, if anything, to do with ZPL.

Answer (score 0):

You say you don't have control over the data in the table, but do you have control over the content/format of `$ItemBarCode$`?

Have the variable contain the `^FD` prefix and `^FS` suffix (and remove from the ZPL code).  When the variable is blank/empty, nothing will print.

Comment: I will contact the software developer and have him try that.  This change would alter the code of every label I've ever made and could cause major problems though.

Comment: According to the consultant, your suggestion is impossible.  I guess the solution is to create a customization in the system's code that allows for a logic line to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the software developer consultant, the solution is to create a customization in the system's code that allows for a logic line to fix this error.  This is not something that can be fixed within ZPL itself, rather, there will be two separate labels. For instance,

```
if single item then print X 
if multiple items then print Y
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same situation. My solution is input barcode command in single line with its data and terminator ^FD and ^FS. So during parsing label file line by line, if data is zero or error than remove entire line. And its work for me